# Look for web application to guide front line staff complete complex procedure

Tags: web-apps, knowledge-base

My client is a bank. The front line staffs need to assist clients on various applications. Depends on various conditions the front line staff need to complete some forms (paper), say some legal terms, ask for manager approval, etc. The procedure involved multiple steps and is very complex.

We are looking for 3rd party solution (web application preferred) to guide front line staff how to complete the procedure. The system can show the staff what is the right procedure and which step he is in.

The management should be easy to change the procedure. e.g. open a bank account require A -> B -> C -> D. Today a new legal enforcement applied, the manager can easily change the step to A -> B -> D -> E -> C.

It sounds like half an expert system and half knowledge-base to me. But I cannot find the right solution on Internet. Could you please advise? Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but possibly a [web-hosted, searchable wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software), such as [TWiki](http://twiki.org/), in which you could create the tutorials yourself.

Comment: Is there any wiki-like application can show the linkage between articles in graph? So the relationship like A->B->C->D would be easily manage and update.